# logging email sent from AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am using AWS SES to send emails. I migrated from mailgun to SES recently. The thing is, I am trying to get the logs of every email that is being sent, the way it was in mailgun. I can also see the statistics on cloudwatch, but I want logs. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following options:

1. You can publish your email sending events to an Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream. This will take metadata from your sent emails and write it to an S3 bucket, which should produce your desired log.

Amazon has a tutorial on implementing this process at the link below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-kinesis-analytics.html

2. You can use an Amazon SNS topic for notifications about email delivery, bounces, or complaints on Amazon SES.

Amazon has a reference guide on implementing this process at the link below:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-email-event-logs/